# Custom SharePoint Timer Job won't run

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, timer

Any reasons why a SharePoint 2010 custom timer job simply won't run? It runs just fine on another server (WFE/CA server) but won't run on a non-WFE server. By 'won't run' I mean "run now" is clicked and the job isn't removed from definitions (as it should, its a one-time), doesn't error out. Logging a message that the job is running is the first thing in the `Execute` definition of the job, but that log never appears... it just doesn't run.

Other server farms we've tested on don't have this issue with non-WFE servers.

Timer service is started and has been restarted.

Comment: Anything showing up in the ULS logs on the server?

Comment: @Robbert Nothing in the ULS logs.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to connect to the Timer process with Visual Studio and debug the code that way.

Comment: @Robbert Not possible because the `Execute` definition of the job is never being hit, so the job itself never executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue on UAT. All I did was delete xml files from:

`c:\programdata\microsoft\sharepoint\config\GUID` (keeping `Cache.ini` intact), did a restart of windows sharepoint timer service from `start-->services, iisreset` and the job ran sucessfully on UAT, but same solution is not working on PROD, check if it works for you.

Comment: Good stuff, this worked.  I guess the timer service hadn't picked up on the changes (new jobs added by my new service) for some reason. [This blog post](http://latenightsp.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/sharepoint-config-cache/) was a good resource for what you described. Doing a timer service recycle to kick off the config refresh also worked. Thanks again!